# Scala MaxBy's Tuple

Tags: scala

I have a `Seq` of Tuples, which represents a word count: `(count, word)`

For Example:

- (5, "Hello")
- (3, "World")

---

My Goal is to find the word with the highest count. In a case **of a tie** between 2 words, I'll pick the word, which appears first in the Dictionary (aka Alphabetical order).

```scala
val wordCounts = Seq(
  (10, "World"),
  (5, "Something"),
  (10, "Hello")
)

val commonWord = wordCounts.maxBy(_._1)
print(commonWord)
```

Now, this code segment will return `(10, "World")`, because this is the first tuple that have the maximum count.

---

I could use `.sortBy` and then `.head`, but I want to be more efficient.

My question is there any way to change the Ordering of the `maxBy`, in order to achieve the desired outcome.

**Note:** I prefer not to use `.sortBy`, because it's `O(n*log(n))` and not `O(n)`. I know that I can use `.reduce`, but I want to check if I can adjust `.maxBy`?

---

Scala Version 2.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own `Ordering` by using `orElse()` to combine two `Ordering`s together:

```
// can't use .orElseBy() because of the .reverse, so this is a bit verbose
val countThenAlphaOrdering =
  Ordering.by[(Int, String), Int](_._1)
          .orElse(Ordering.by[(Int, String), String](_._2).reverse)
```

Or you can use `Ordering.Tuple2` in this case:

```
val countThenAlphaOrdering = Ordering.Tuple2(Ordering[Int], Ordering[String].reverse)
```

Then

```
val wordCounts = Seq(
  (10, "World"),
  (5, "Something"),
  (10, "Hello"),
)

wordCounts.max(countThenAlphaOrdering)  // (10,Hello): (Int, String)
```

Comment: Works properly, and much more easier to maintain.

Answer (score 4):

Functions like `max`, `min`, `maxBy` and `minBy` use implicit `Ordering` that defines the comparison between two items. There's a default implementation of `Ordering` for Tuple2, however the problem is it will apply the same comparison to both elements – while in your case you need to use *greater than* for _._1 and *less than* for _._2. However you can easily solve this by inverting the first element, so this does the trick:

```
wordCounts.minBy(x => (-x._1, x._2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
implicit val WordSorter: Ordering[(Int, String)] = new Ordering[(Int, String)]{
    override def compare(
      x: (Int, String), 
      y: (Int, String)
    ) = {
      val iComp = implicitly[Ordering[Int]].compare(x._1, y._1)
      if iComp == 0
        -implicitly[Ordering[String]].compare(x._2, y._2)
      else
        iComp
    }
  }
  
  val seq = Seq(
    (10, "World"),
    (5, "Something"),
    (10, "Hello")
  )

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = println(seq.max)
```

You can create your own `Ordering[(Int, String)]` implicit whose compare method returns the comparison of the numbers in the tuples if its not zero and the comparison of the strings negatively if the int comparison is zero. Using implicitly defined `Ordering[Int]` and `Ordering[String]` for modularity if you want to change the behaviour later on. If you don't want to use those, you can just replace
`implicitly[Orderint[Int]].compare(x._1, y._1)` with `x._1.compareTo(y._1)` and so on.